# How do I store a list (or dict) of key terms from a regular expression? -Python

Tags: python, regex, dictionary

I am quite new at python and regex so please bear with me.
I am trying to read in a file, match a particular name using a regex while ignoring the case, and store each time I find it. For example, if the file is composed of `Bill bill biLl biLL`, I need to store each variation in a dictionary or list.
Current code:

```
import re
import sys
import fileinput
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "flag"
    pattern = re.compile("""([b][i][l][l])""")
    for line in fileinput.input():
        variation=set(pattern.search(line, re.I))

    print variation.groupdict()
    print "flag2"
```

When ran, the code will return an error: 'NoneType' cannot be iterated (or something along those lines).
So how do I store each variation?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why the square brackets? `[b]` is equivalent to `b`, since square brackets indicate character classes (i.e. `[abc]` = "any of a, b or c").

Comment: `([b][i][l][l])` What an extremely weird regex. I assume that's not what you want to do

Comment: yea I was using `[b][i][l][l]` until I got something started.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use findall:

```
re.findall(r'bill', open(filename).read(), re.I)
```

Easy as pie:

```
>>> s = 'fooBiLL bill BILL bIlL foo bar'
>>> import re
>>> re.findall(r'bill', s, re.I)
['BiLL', 'bill', 'BILL', 'bIlL']
```

Comment: so should I use `variation=set(pattern.findall(line, re.I))`
I am using the set so there are no duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

I think that you want [re.findall](http://localhost/docs/python-2.7-docs-html/library/re.html#re.findall). This is of course available on the compiled regular expression as well. The particular error code that you are getting though, would seem to indicate that you are [not matching your pattern](http://localhost/docs/python-2.7-docs-html/library/re.html#re.search). try

```
pattern = re.compile("bill", re.IGNORE_CASE)
```